# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call, Linear Function

Tags: python

Ok so i have this program right here:

```
n = int(input("x"))
def fct_aff_morc(n): 
    if n<0:
        f(n)=-2*n+3
    if n>=0:
        f(n)=2*n+3
```

And I get "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"
I don't get why ^^' pls help me

Comment: what does `f(n) = -2*n+3` mean for you what do you want to achieve ? if `f` defined ? `f(n)` is a call to a method `f`, that's not at all how you store a linear function

Comment: Do you mean `return 2*abs(n) + 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
n = int(input(x))
def fct_aff_morc(n): 
    if n<0:
        return (-2*n)+3
    if n>=0:
        return (2*n)+3

print(fct_aff_morc(n))
```